# system.reflection.targetException c# error

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have an MVC app that I am getting a system.reflection.targetexception non-static method requires a target this happens on my base controller when I am re-directing them to the right spot of my app I am just basically trying to updatelastlogindate.

```
 case "employeecenter":
                                Common.AppName = "Employee Center";
                                if (Session["LLD_EmpCenter"] == null)
                                {
                                    Session["LLD_EmpCenter"] = true;
                                    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            Common.Instance.UpdateLastLoginDate(User.Identity.Name);
                                        }
                                        catch (ArgumentException e)
                                        {

                                        }
                                    });
                                }
```

the error happens on common.instance.updateLastloginDatewith the user.identity.name which does have a value it is not null so I am not sure why the error is happening. even having a try catch around this still throws this exception and causes my debugger to stop.

```
 namespace KMSSecurity
    {
        public class Common : IDisposable
        {
            public Common();

            public static string AppName { get; set; }
            public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
            public static Common Instance { get; }
            public KMSSecurityContext Context { get; protected set; }

            public bool ChangeAppPermissionForUser(Guid appId, string userName, bool grant);
            public bool ChangeCategoryPermissionForUser(int categoryId, string userName, bool grant);
            public bool ChangePassword(string userName, string oldPassword, string newPassword);
            public void ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password, string passwordquestion, string passwordanswer);
            public bool ChangePermissionForUser(Guid roleId, int categoryid, string permissionName, string userName, bool grant);
            public bool ChangePermissionForUser(Guid roleId, string permissionName, string userName, bool grant);
            public bool ChangeRolePermissionForUser(Guid roleId, string userName, bool grant);
            public void CopyUserPermissions(string userNameFrom, string userNameTo, Guid appId);
            public void CopyUserPermissions(string userNameFrom, string userNameTo, string applicationName);
            public Guid CreateApplication(string appName);
            public int CreateCategory(string appName, string roleName, string categoryName, string categoryDesc, int displayOrder);
            public bool CreatePermission(string permissionName, string permissionDesc, string permissionHelpText, int displayOrder, int categoryId);
            public Guid? CreateRole(string appName, string roleName, string roleDescription);
            public MembershipUser CreateUser(string userName, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer);
            public MembershipUser CreateUser(string userName, string passWord, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer);
            public UserPermissions CreateUserPermissions();
            public UserPermissions CreateUserPermissions(string userName);
            public UserPermissions CreateUserPermissions(string userName, List<Role> initialPerms);
            public UserPermissions CreateUserPermissions(string appName, string userName);
            public bool DeleteApplication(Guid applicationId);
            public bool DeleteCategory(int categoryId, bool deleteOnlyIfIsEmpty);
            public bool DeleteCategory(string appName, string roleName, string categoryName, bool deleteOnlyIfIsEmpty);
            public bool DeletePermission(Guid appId, Guid roleId, int categoryId, string permissionName, bool deleteOnlyIfRoleIsEmpty);
            public bool DeleteRole(string appName, string roleName, bool deleteOnlyIfRoleIsEmpty);
            public bool DeleteRole(Guid roleId, bool deleteOnlyIfRoleIsEmpty);
            public bool DeleteUser(string userName);
            public void DisableLogin(string userName);
            public bool EditCategory(int id, string name, string desc, int displayOrder);
            public bool EditPermission(int categoryId, string permissionName, string permissionDesc, string permissionHelpText, int displayOrder, int newCategoryId);
            public bool EditRole(Guid id, string desc);
            public void EnableLogin(string userName);
            public List<Security_User> GetAdministrators();
            public List<Security_User> GetAllUsers();
            public Application GetApplication(Guid applicationId);
            public List<Application> GetApplications();
            public List<Security_User> GetApplicationUsers(Guid applicationId);
            public int GetAvailableDisplayOrder(int categoryId);
            public int GetAvailableDisplayOrder(Guid roleId);
            public List<Role> GetAvailablePermissions(string appName);
            public List<string> GetCategoriesNames(string appName, string roleName);
            public Security_Category GetCategory(int id);
            public Security_Category GetCategory(string appName, string roleName, string categoryName);
            public List<string> GetCategoryPermissionNames(int categoryId);
            public List<string> GetCategoryPermissionNames(string appName, string roleName, string categoryName);
            public User GetCombinedUser(string userName);
            public string GetPasswordQuestion(string userName);
            public Security_Permissions GetPermission(int categoryId, string permissionName);
            public List<Security_Permissions> GetPermissionsForRole(string roleName, string appName);
            public List<Security_Permissions> GetPermissionsForRole(string appName, string roleName, string categoryName);
            public Role GetRole(Guid roleId);
            public Role GetRole(string roleName, string appName);
            public List<Security_Category> GetRoleCategories(string roleName, string appName);
            public List<string> GetRoleNames(string appName);
            public List<string> GetRolePermissionNames(string roleName, string appName);
            public ICollection<Role> GetRoles(Guid applicationId);
            public List<Role> GetRolesForUser(string appName, string userName);
            public List<Security_User> GetUserForAllApps(string userName);
            public Security_User GetUserForApp(string userName, string appName);
            public List<Security_User> GetUserForPermission(int categoryId, string permissionName);
            public MembershipUser MembershipUser(string userName);
            public string ResetPassword(string userName, string passwordAnswer);
            public bool ResetPassword(string userName, string defaultPassword = "", string passWordSalt = "", int passwordFormat = 1);
            public bool RoleExists(string roleName, string appName);
            public bool UnlockUser(string userName);
            public void UpdateEmail(string userName, string email);
            public void UpdateLastLoginDate(string username);
        }
    }
```

This is my common class and it is expecting a username which is getting passed to the updateLastLoginDate any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell for sure.

It looks like the static Instance value of the Common class is not set.

Do you need to add a static constructor to set that?

```
namespace KMSSecurity
{
    public class Common : IDisposable
    {
        public Common();
        static Common()
        {
            Instance = new Common();
        }
        public static string AppName { get; set; }
        public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public static Common Instance { get; }
        public KMSSecurityContext Context { get; protected set; }

        public bool ChangeAppPermissionForUser(Guid appId, string userName, bool grant);
        public bool ChangeCategoryPermissionForUser(int categoryId, string userName, bool grant);
        public bool ChangePassword(string userName, string oldPassword, string newPassword);
        public void ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password, string passwordquestion, string passwordanswer);
        public bool ChangePermissionForUser(Guid roleId, int categoryid, string permissionName, string userName, bool grant);
        public bool ChangePermissionForUser(Guid roleId, string permissionName, string userName, bool grant);
        public bool ChangeRolePermissionForUser(Guid roleId, string userName, bool grant);
        public void CopyUserPermissions(string userNameFrom, string userNameTo, Guid appId);
        public void CopyUserPermissions(string userNameFrom, string userNameTo, string applicationName);
        public Guid CreateApplication(string appName);
        public int CreateCategory(string appName, string roleName, string categoryName, string categoryDesc, int displayOrder);
        public bool CreatePermission(string permissionName, string permissionDesc, string permissionHelpText, int displayOrder, int categoryId);
        public Guid? CreateRole(string appName, string roleName, string roleDescription);
        public MembershipUser CreateUser(string userName, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer);
        public MembershipUser CreateUser(string userName, string passWord, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer);
        public UserPermissions CreateUserPermissions();
        public UserPermissions CreateUserPermissions(string userName);
        public UserPermissions CreateUserPermissions(string userName, List<Role> initialPerms);
        public UserPermissions CreateUserPermissions(string appName, string userName);
        public bool DeleteApplication(Guid applicationId);
        public bool DeleteCategory(int categoryId, bool deleteOnlyIfIsEmpty);
        public bool DeleteCategory(string appName, string roleName, string categoryName, bool deleteOnlyIfIsEmpty);
        public bool DeletePermission(Guid appId, Guid roleId, int categoryId, string permissionName, bool deleteOnlyIfRoleIsEmpty);
        public bool DeleteRole(string appName, string roleName, bool deleteOnlyIfRoleIsEmpty);
        public bool DeleteRole(Guid roleId, bool deleteOnlyIfRoleIsEmpty);
        public bool DeleteUser(string userName);
        public void DisableLogin(string userName);
        public bool EditCategory(int id, string name, string desc, int displayOrder);
        public bool EditPermission(int categoryId, string permissionName, string permissionDesc, string permissionHelpText, int displayOrder, int newCategoryId);
        public bool EditRole(Guid id, string desc);
        public void EnableLogin(string userName);
        public List<Security_User> GetAdministrators();
        public List<Security_User> GetAllUsers();
        public Application GetApplication(Guid applicationId);
        public List<Application> GetApplications();
        public List<Security_User> GetApplicationUsers(Guid applicationId);
        public int GetAvailableDisplayOrder(int categoryId);
        public int GetAvailableDisplayOrder(Guid roleId);
        public List<Role> GetAvailablePermissions(string appName);
        public List<string> GetCategoriesNames(string appName, string roleName);
        public Security_Category GetCategory(int id);
        public Security_Category GetCategory(string appName, string roleName, string categoryName);
        public List<string> GetCategoryPermissionNames(int categoryId);
        public List<string> GetCategoryPermissionNames(string appName, string roleName, string categoryName);
        public User GetCombinedUser(string userName);
        public string GetPasswordQuestion(string userName);
        public Security_Permissions GetPermission(int categoryId, string permissionName);
        public List<Security_Permissions> GetPermissionsForRole(string roleName, string appName);
        public List<Security_Permissions> GetPermissionsForRole(string appName, string roleName, string categoryName);
        public Role GetRole(Guid roleId);
        public Role GetRole(string roleName, string appName);
        public List<Security_Category> GetRoleCategories(string roleName, string appName);
        public List<string> GetRoleNames(string appName);
        public List<string> GetRolePermissionNames(string roleName, string appName);
        public ICollection<Role> GetRoles(Guid applicationId);
        public List<Role> GetRolesForUser(string appName, string userName);
        public List<Security_User> GetUserForAllApps(string userName);
        public Security_User GetUserForApp(string userName, string appName);
        public List<Security_User> GetUserForPermission(int categoryId, string permissionName);
        public MembershipUser MembershipUser(string userName);
        public string ResetPassword(string userName, string passwordAnswer);
        public bool ResetPassword(string userName, string defaultPassword = "", string passWordSalt = "", int passwordFormat = 1);
        public bool RoleExists(string roleName, string appName);
        public bool UnlockUser(string userName);
        public void UpdateEmail(string userName, string email);
        public void UpdateLastLoginDate(string username);
    }
}
```

Comment: static Common(){ Instance = new Common()};

Comment: I guess I am not really getting what I should do I could add private static Common instance = new Common() then call to it using instance.UpdateLastLoginDate(User.Identity.Name); but that seems like it would be doing the same thing I am already doing it didn't like static Common() {Instance = new Common()}

Comment: it is saying static common method needs a return type I really don't understand the reflection basically all that is doing is taking the username and updating a table when they last logged in inside that class so  it is expecting a string which I am passing in so not really sure why that error is happening. I uploaded the code in my dev env and it does not break on the server